# JAVA REST API Как правильно делать

Tags: java, java-ee, rest

Не совсем понимаю как должна выглядеть структура проекта, соответствующая REST API. На данный момент у меня есть простой сервлет

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
public class AuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        try {

            String query=sb.toString();
             Object o= ClientQueryService.queryHandler(query);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().write(o.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            response.getWriter().write(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

В запросе я передаю строку json например такого вида:

```
{\"method\":\"addRoom\",\"allParamList\":[{\"type\":\"room\",\"id\":12,\"number\":22,\"cost\":33,\"capacity\":123,\"stars\":55,\"status\":\"FREE\"}]}");
```

сервлет отправляет json классу ClientQueryService, который возвращает ответ также в виде json объекта. Мне нужно переделать это в rest api.  После гугла до меня не особо доходит, что нужно делать и какие технологии использовать. Можно ли сделать rest сервис на основе сервлета? Что использовать? Вроде есть JAX-RS и разные его реализации...
 Может кто-нибудь описать цепочку выполнения простого запроса без каких-то навороченных фреймворков? Просто чтобы работало. Например добавить пользователя. Типа запрос посылается на сервлет, сервлет посылает на какой-нибудь rest и он что-то делает...

Comment: Вы хоите из сервлета обращаться к стороннему REST-сервису, или сервлет и должен быть REST-сервисом?

Comment: REST сервис должен быть мой собственный. Просто где-то читал , что его можно и на основе сервлета сделать. А так без разницы.

Comment: Можно. Привяжите сервлет к урлу `/room`, реализуйте обработку POST/GET/PUT/DELETE запросов, а из тела запроса выкиньте свойство `method` (тип операции должен определяться HTTP-методом). И вот вам будет простенький REST на голом сервлете. Но на JAX-RS получится более лаконичный, поддерживаемый код, а REST выйдет ближе к стандартам.

Comment: Как я понял, для использования JAX-RS мне нужно только соответствующим образом поставить аннотации над методами и все? Например                                                                                              @GET
@Path("/user") public Task getTask(@QueryParam("iuser") String user) {
 }    И не надо ничего нигде прописывать в web.xml например?? И нормально ли передавать json объект(например новый пользователь) в параметре запроса, или нужно передавать только отдельные данные типа  имя, фамилия...? Тот метод, над которым я прописал post аннотацию автоматически получит QueryParam?

Comment: Аннотации только размечают ваш сервис. Так или иначе обработкой запросов занимается конкретная реализация JAX-RS (CXF, Resteasy, Jersey) и вам надо сконфигурировать ее для вашего контейнера (web.xml) или самостоятельного приложения (тогда никакого web.xml не будет вовсе). JSON (данные) передается в теле запроса. В query-параметрах принято передавать метаданные вроде фильтров, флагов, условий.